# Updating a column in multiple tables with a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, auto-update

I have a couple QA columns in every table of my Oracle database that I want to update daily with the value of the username who inserted/updated an object. I am able to update the column manually in on table as the following:

```
UPDATE TEST.TABLE1 TB
SET TB.ADDED_BY2 = 
(
select IA.FULL_NAME
from ISM.APP_USER IA
where IA.NAME = UPPER(TB.ADDED_BY)
),
TB.CHANGED_BY2 = 
(
select IA.FULL_NAME
from ISM.APP_USER IA
where IA.NAME = UPPER(TB.CHANGED_BY)
)
where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATUM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE) AND ADDED_BY2 IS NULL;
```

But to update the same column in 25 tables is a tedious (and boring) job. The question is: is there anyway to update the columns in the 25 tables using a LOOP (or any other method)?

My ultimage goal is to do something as the following:

```
FOR I IN SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TEST.TABLE1', 'TEST.TABLE2')

LOOP

UPDATE I.TABLE_NAME TB
SET TB.ADDED_BY2 = 
(
select IA.FULL_NAME
from ISM.APP_USER IA
where IA.NAME = UPPER(TB.ADDED_BY)
),
TB.CHANGED_BY2 = 
(
select IA.FULL_NAME
from ISM.APP_USER IA
where IA.NAME = UPPER(TB.CHANGED_BY)
)
where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATUM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE) AND ADDED_BY2 IS NULL;

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
FOR I IN SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TEST.TABLE1', 'TEST.TABLE2')

LOOP
 execute immediate
  'UPDATE ' || I.TABLE_NAME || ' TB
   SET TB.ADDED_BY2 = 
   (
     select IA.FULL_NAME
     from ISM.APP_USER IA
     where IA.NAME = UPPER(TB.ADDED_BY)
   ),
   TB.CHANGED_BY2 = 
   (
     select IA.FULL_NAME
     from ISM.APP_USER IA
     where IA.NAME = UPPER(TB.CHANGED_BY)
   )
   where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATUM, ''YYYY-MM-DD'') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE)
     AND ADDED_BY2 IS NULL';

END LOOP;
```

This way, you dynamically build an SQL statement, based on varying table name, and execute it;